# Give user rights to change network settings

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003

I'm not very well versed in using windows server administrations tools and I cant figure out how to solve my problem. I got a user which needs to be able to change its networks settings.

It's an account shared by two persons and they use the computer to plug in to different machines and to be able to communicate they need to be able to change ip address. They shouldn't have administration rights, just be able to do this and I cant figure out how to do this.

We are running windows server 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the users to the local Network Operators group.  This allows them to access `ncpa.cpl` and change network settings.

Comment: I added the user to the group I think is right, our localization is Swedish but there was a group that's translated to Responsible for network configuration. But I still get the massage when logged in on that account that I lack authorization to configure network connection.

Comment: I figured out how to get the results I needed. Instead of going via the server I logged on as admin on the computer and under mange -> groups added the user to the group there. It was named the same but I had to go a different route. Thanks for the help!